# Selenium Web Driver If-Else condition to choose button1 or button2 or button3

Tags: selenium, web, button, click, driver

I'm  just started to study Java if
result6 = list6.toArray(result6)

1. If  result6[a] = 2  click button1
2. If  result6[a] = 3  click button2
3. If  result6[a] = 4  click button3

```java
if (result6[a] == 2) 
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="row1"]/div[14]/img")).click(); 

if (result6[a] == 3) 
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="row2"]/div[14]/img")).click();   

if (result6[a] == 4)    
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="row3"]/div[14]/img")).click();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String elementId;
switch(result6[a]) {
    case 2: elementId = "row1";
            break;
    case 3: elementId = "row2";
            break;
    case 4: elementId = "row3";
            break;
}
String xpath = String.format("//*[@id=\"%s\"]/div[14]/img", elementId);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).click();
```